# Pre-configured signature in DocuSign Mobile SDK

Tags: android, docusignapi

I'm using the Mobile SDK to access DocuSign features via Android application (Kotlin).

For authentication, I'm using JWT.

My question is:
Is it possible to use a pre-defined signature (not sure if it's the correct term) like  on the web? I mean something like this:
[image]

I've tried both `signOffline` and `signOnline`. In both cases, just the draw/handwriting signature is supported. I also already tried to call `drawSignature` and `drawInitials`, but doesn't seem do have any effect.

Could someone give some hint how to do this?

Answer (score 2):

Currently, SDK supports only drawing of signature in both offline and online signing. Predefined signature is not supported yet in online signing. We will definitely add this feature to our Roadmap and will be available in future SDK releases.

Answer (score 0):

We released SDK v1.4.0. In this release, we added support for using preconfigured signature in online signing.
Set the following SDK CustomSettings api as follows:

```
val customSettingsDelegate = DocuSign.getInstance().getCustomSettingsDelegate()
customSettingsDelegate.disableNativeComponentsInOnlineSigning(this, true)
```